# Switch Statement Java Script

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Trying to assign colors to a variety of polygons. I am not sure I am doing this correctly. I was using an if else statement, but a coworker advised using a switch statement. I cannot get the code below to work.

I am new to javascript, but I wanted to try and make a map on leaflet. I started following a tutorial found here: maptimeboston.github.io/leaflet-intro. I have been subbing in my own data. I found that when I used the else if statement such as in the tutorial all the polygons get assigned the first assigned color

```js
$.getJSON("SA_Access.geojson", function(accesspolys) {
  L.geoJson(accesspolys, {
    style: function(feature) {
      var fillColor,
        servicelayer = feature.properties.POLYID;
      switch (servicelayer) {
        case '10987':
          fillColor = "#006837";
          break;
        case '10988':
          fillcolor = "#31a354";
          break;
        default:
          fillColor = "#FFFFFF"
      }
    }
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
      layer.bindPopup("<strong>" + feature.properties.POLYNAME)
    }
  }).addTo(map);
});
```

Originally my code looked like below:

```
$.getJSON("SA_Access.geojson",function(accesspolys){
  L.geoJson( accesspolys, {
      style: function(feature){
        var fillColor,
            servicelayer = feature.properties.POLYID;
        if (servicelayer = '10987' ) fillColor = "#006837";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10988' ) fillColor = "#31a354";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10989' ) fillColor = "#78c679";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10990' ) fillColor = "#c2e699";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10991' ) fillColor = "#800000";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10992' ) fillColor = "#FFFF00";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10993' ) fillColor = "#00FF00";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10994' ) fillColor = "#808000";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10995' ) fillColor = "#ff6347";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10996' ) fillColor = "#ee82ee";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10997' ) fillColor = "#6a5acd";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10998' ) fillColor = "#ffa500";
        else if ( servicelayer = '10999' ) fillColor = "#3cb371";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11100' ) fillColor = "#87554A";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11101' ) fillColor = "#685ab3";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11102' ) fillColor = "#2b42d9";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11103' ) fillColor = "#d92bb4";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11152' ) fillColor = "#982880";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11153' ) fillColor = "#459828";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11154' ) fillColor = "#288398";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11155' ) fillColor = "#982891";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11156' ) fillColor = "#284e98";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11157' ) fillColor = "#982860";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11158' ) fillColor = "#989428";
        else if ( servicelayer = '11159' ) fillColor = "#362898";
        else fillColor = "#f7f7f7";  // no data
        return { color: "#999", weight: 1, fillColor: fillColor, fillOpacity: .6 };
      },
      onEachFeature: function( feature, layer ){
        layer.bindPopup( "<strong>" + feature.properties.POLYNAME)
      }
    }).addTo(map);
  });
```

Comment: You are not even using `fillColor` anywhere.

Comment: What is the exact problem? Errors? Wrong output?

Comment: I don't know what library you're using here, but you have a syntax error (missing comma after the value of `style`). Also does `style` accept a function? You are not returning anything from that function, so my guess would be that even if it does, it wouldn't do anything.

Comment: Wild guess, but maybe you need to return fillColor in the function? Seems like you want to use that one?

Comment: I still don't understand your problem. Do you have a problem or do you want it neater?

Comment: I am new to javascript, but I wanted to try and make a map on leaflet. I started following a tutorial found here: https://maptimeboston.github.io/leaflet-intro/. I have been subbing in my own data. I found that when I used the else if statement such as in the tutorial all the polygons get assigned the first assigned color.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a map that your function can lookup in. With no hit it becomes `undefined` and thus you can use `||` to produce the default.

```
const colorMap = {
    10987: '#006837', 
    10988: '#31a354', 
    10989: '#78c679', 
    // etc
};

function getColor(serviceLayer) {
  return colorMap[serviceLayer] || '#f7f7f7';
}


getColor(999);
// => '#f7f7f7'
getColor(10988);
// => '#31a354'
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're taking a value, and outputting a different value in this scenario you'd do well to use some kind of key-value dictionary pattern.

The simplest implementation is to use a multi-dimensional array, like

```
var items = [
    [10987, "#31a354"],
    [10989, "#78c679"],
    [10990, "#c2e699"]
];
```

Then write a simple function to match a value in element 0 (i.e. 10987) and return element 1 (i.e. "#31a354")

```
function getValue(dict, key)
    for(var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++)
        if(dict[i][0] == key){
            return dict[i][1];
        }
    }
    return "somedefaultvalue";
}
```

The more structured approach might be to assemble a json object like:

```
var items = [
    {"key": 10987, "value": "#31a354"},
    {"key": 10989, "value": "#78c679"},
    {"key": 10990, "value": "#c2e699"},
];
```

Which looks similar, sure, but reads better when you iterate rather than just referring to the elements as item[0][1] you would have item[0].key.

```
function getValue(dict, key)
    for(var i = 0; i < dict.length; i++)
        if(dict[i].key == key){
            return dict[i].value;
        }
    }
    return "somedefaultvalue";
}
```

in both cases, you'd invoke the getValue a bit like this, i'm assuming throughout that the "key" is an integerial data type - it could easily be converted to a string or whatever if needed though.

```
var fillColor = getValue(items, 10987);
```

** apologies, wrote all of this freehand so there might be some tidying involved. Hope it helps!

edit: the json approach is great if you ever want to extend your app to read in the values from an external file or a service of some kind, which is quite a normal practise in this sort of scenario.